# How to sort an array dates in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, nsdateformatter

I have an array of dates like this :-

```
  var dateArray = ["2016-04-20", "2016-04-22", "2016-04-25", "2016-04-30"]
```

and I want to find out the difference of days between them. I do some research and i am able to do that with only two dates here is the approach i did in finding the difference between two date

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
let isoDate = "2016-04-20"
let calendar = NSCalendar.current
let currentDate = Date()
```

And in my **viewDidLoad** method I did this

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



//  let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: )
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") //en_US_POSIX
    let formatedStartDate = dateFormatter.date(from: isoDate)
    let date = dateArray.compactMap { dateFormatter.date(from: $0) } // for date array
    print(date)
    let components = Set<Calendar.Component>([.day])
    let differenceOfDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents(components, from: formatedStartDate!, to: currentDate )

    print (differenceOfDate)
    apiData()
}
```

As you can see in the code i created a constant **let isoDate = "2016-04-20"** and changed into **formatedStartDate** and find the difference between form this date to current date then it worked. But what if I have my own array of dates and how can i find the difference of my own array of dates and sort it into increasing or decreasing order. Please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Create the date formatter

  ```
  let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
  dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") //en_US_POSIX
  ```
- Map the date string array to `Date` instances

  ```
  let dateStringArray = ["2016-04-20", "2016-04-22", "2016-04-25", "2016-04-30"]
  let dateArray = dateStringArray.map {dateFormatter.date(from: $0)!} // add .sorted() if the array is unordered.
  ```
- In a loop get the differences between adjacent items

  ```
  var differences = [Int]()
  for i in 0..<dateArray.count - 1 {
      let dayComponent = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: dateArray[i], to: dateArray[i+1])
      differences.append(dayComponent.day!)
  }
  print(differences)
  ```

Comment: It worked Sir but one thing i want to do more I want to print that dates in decreasing order. How can I do that?

Comment: `print(Array(differences.reversed()))` or append `.sorted(by: >)` to the `dateStringArray` line and swap `[i]` with `[i+1]`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you only want to compare the dates next to each other or compare each and every date. In the first case go with `vadian`s solution. In the other case you can do something like this:

```
let dateStrings = ["2016-04-20", "2016-04-22", "2016-04-25", "2016-04-30"]

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

let dates = dateStrings.compactMap { dateFormatter.date(from: $0) }

let calendar = Calendar.current

var differences: [Int] = []
for i in 0..<dates.count {
    for j in i + 1..<dates.count {
        if let difference = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: dates[i], to: dates[j]).day {
            differences.append(difference)
        }
    }
}

let descendingDifferences = differences.sorted(by: >)
print(descendingDifferences) // results in [10, 8, 5, 5, 3, 2]
```